# How do I get jQuery Fancybox to accept my object as a valid open parameter?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object, fancybox

I have some html in this format:

```
<div id="logos" class="downloadlist">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/toolkit/logos/download.jpg" data-image="images/toolkit/logos/one.jpg">First Logo</a></li>
        <li><a href="/toolkit/logos/download.jpg" data-image="images/toolkit/logos/two.jpg">Second Logo</a></li>
        <li><a href="/toolkit/logos/download.jpg" data-image="images/toolkit/logos/three.jpg">Third Logo</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to step through it and provide it to Fancybox [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/DR7eC/2/).

I've got as far as this, but it's straight-up not working:

```
downloadList = $('#logos ul li a');

var downloadArray = {};

downloadJSON = '';

$.each(downloadList, function(d)
{
    var download = $(this);
    var href = download.data('image');
    var title = download[0].innerText;
    var link = download[0].href;

    downloadArray[d] = {};
    downloadArray[d].href = href;
    downloadArray[d].title = "<a href=\'" + link + "\'>"+title+"</a>";

    downloadJSON += JSON.stringify(downloadArray[d])+',';
});

downloadJSON = downloadJSON.slice(0, -1);

$.fancybox.open([downloadArray]);
```

downloadJSON gives me:

```
{"href":"images/toolkit/logos/one.jpg","title":"<a href='http://example.com/toolkit/logos/download.jpg'>First Logo</a>"},{"href":"images/toolkit/logos/two.jpg","title":"<a href='http://example.com/toolkit/logos/download.jpg'>Second Logo</a>"},{"href":"images/toolkit/logos/three.jpg","title":"<a href='http://example.com/toolkit/logos/download.jpg'>Third Logo</a>"}
```

JSON.stringify-ing the downloadArray object gives me:

```
{"0":{"href":"images/toolkit/logos/one.jpg","title":"<a href='http://example.com/toolkit/logos/download.jpg'>First Logo</a>"},"1":{"href":"images/toolkit/logos/two.jpg","title":"<a href='http://example.com/toolkit/logos/download.jpg'>Second Logo</a>"},"2":{"href":"images/toolkit/logos/three.jpg","title":"<a href='http://example.com/toolkit/logos/download.jpg'>Third Logo</a>"}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
links = [];
$('#logos ul li a').each(function() {
   links.push({
      href: $(this).attr('data-image'),
      title: "<a href=\'" + $(this).attr('href') + "\'>"+$(this).html()+"</a>"
   });
});
//JSON.stringify(links);
$.fancybox.open(links);
```

Comment: +1 : however, this will open fancybox on page load. In order to select the proper logo to download, we would need to set the API option `index`. see my answer

Comment: @Adrian thank you, this was perfect for my needs, since I already had the actual code inside a .on click event.

Looks like I was wildly overcomplicating things!

Answer (score 1):

My extended answer based on @Adrian's answer :

In order to download (show in fancybox) the proper logo according to the link selected, we use the API option `index` like in the following tweaked extended code :

```
links = [];
$('#logos ul li a').each(function (indx) {
  // Adrain's code tweaked
  links.push({
    href: $(this).data('image'),
    title: "<a href=\'" + $(this).data('image') + "\'>" + $(this).html() + "</a>"
  });
  // extended to catch click on links
  $(this).on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.fancybox.open(links, {
      index: indx // starts gallery with index of the clicked link
    });
  });
});
//JSON.stringify(links);
//$.fancybox.open(links); // would open fancybox on page load
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdwZ5/)**

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate you extending Adrian's answer. I marked that one as best - it was perfect for me, since I already have it wrapped up in a click event. But this is probably a better answer for most use cases.