# Fancybox triggering

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox, eventtrigger

When you show 6 images (all belong to 1 album), you trigger one of this images. It should open the gallery with the selected image instead of the first image of the album. How can I accomplish this?

Code example:

```
$("a[rel=modellen]").click(function () {
    $.fancybox.open([ <? php
    $i = 0;
    foreach($product_fotos as $null = > $object) {
        $i++;
        echo '{';
        echo "href : 'http://wubububu/uploads/products/".$object - > productId.
        "/".$object - > id.
        ".".$object - > extensie.
        "'";
        if (count($product_fotos) != $i) echo '},';
        else echo '}';
    } ?> ]);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: to begin with, where are you populating `$product_fotos` from in your loop?

Comment: doesn't matter, is filled

Comment: use the API option `index`, which in this case should be equal to the value of `i` for each element, however bear in mind that the first element should have `index=0` so you should increment `i` after you set the fancybox's `index`

Comment: if you are wondering, this is where you set the option : `$.fancybox.open([],{ index: i});` so you should't close your php loop until you can pass the value of `i`

Comment: check this for more about the use of `index` http://stackoverflow.com/a/14329183/1055987

Comment: Thanks JFK! I'll take a look at it tonight. Looks promesing!

Comment: JFK, please commit your comment as an answer. Solved my problem with your advise. Completely forgot I can also use the each() method. Thanks bro!

Answer (score -1):

try below

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $("a[rel=modellen]").click(function() {

<?php
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($product_fotos as $null => $object)
        {   
 ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                $.fancybox({
                        'width'             : 500,
                        'height'            : 150,
                        'autoScale'         : true,
                        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                        'href'              : 'http://wubububu/uploads/products/<?php echo $object->productId;?>/<?php echo $object->id.".".$object->extensie;?>'

                    });

            </script>
 <?php
        }
        ?>
   });
            </script>
```

hope it'll help you.

Comment: Not a valid result at all. Type = iframe? Where did I mention I wanted to load iFrame content? I load specific 6 images on my page (6 visible from the 12). When i click on one of the 6 the selected should open with the gallery of 12 pictures.

Comment: this redeclares the function for every matching element.

Comment: Well perhaps you should think twice then. Look your code snippet again.. read it line by line. You actually think a script tag will work inside a click method from jQuery?